# What beside document.readyState could help in telling if a page is loaded in Selenium with Phantom.js in Java?

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, phantomjs

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
            ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));

    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

My problem is that sometimes (when the page takes long to load) the screenshot is taken even though it is not fully loaded. The document.readyState does not seem sufficient in this case. 
Also, I tried adding another condition: jQuery.active == 0, but that just blocked taking the screenshot and resulted in timeout exception. 
I don't want to make the program wait a specific amount of time. 
I will be making screenshots of many different sites and not all of them are build in the same way so waiting for a specific element to be clickable also does not seem right.

Does maybe anyone know how to fix it or if it is even fixable?

Comment: Check out http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp. You should be able to tell your selenium driver to wait until a certain element is available on the page, rather than waiting for `document.readyState` to execute.

Comment: Yes, but in many different websites how can I know what element to suggest?